# Apollo iOS codegen: Nested use of a fragment in a mutation creates unexpected property types in Fragments struct

Tags: swift, code-generation, apollo, apollo-ios

I have the following fragment:

```
fragment User on UserResponse {
    firstName
    lastName
    emailAddress
    emailConsent
    phoneNumber
}
```

When used as root in a mutation, the code generation will correctly generate a root `User` struct in `API.swift` and use that struct as the type of **user** properties in `Fragments`

Eg.:

```
mutation updateUserYourInformation($phoneNumber: String!, $emailConsent: Boolean!) {
    updateUser(phoneNumber: $phoneNumber, emailConsent: $emailConsent) {
        ...User
    }
}
```

and

```
mutation addRelations($spouse: Boolean!, $children: Int!, $roomMates: Int!) {
     addRelations(spouse: $spouse, roommates: $roomMates, children: $children) {
        ...User
    }
}
```

will generate mutations where both `UpdateUserYourInformationMutation.Data.UpdateUser.Fragments` and `AddRelationsMutation.Data.AddRelation.Fragments` has a **user** property of the same struct type `User`.

However, when nesting the fragment in a mutation it generates a nested `User` struct within the Mutation struct, which will be the type of the **user** property in the generated nested `Fragments` struct. E.g:

```
mutation exchangePin($email: String!, $pin: String!) {
    exchangePinForToken(email: $email, pin: $pin) {
        valid
        user {
            ...User
        }
        authToken
        remainingAttempts
    }
}
```

will generate `ExchangePinMutation.Data.ExchangePinForToken.User` and `ExchangePinMutation.Data.ExchangePinForToken.User.Fragments` structs. However, the **user** property of `ExchangePinMutation.Data.ExchangePinForToken.User.Fragments` is of type `ExchangePinMutation.Data.ExchangePinForToken.User` and not of type `User`, as I would have expected.

Consequently, the types differ and in order to update the current `User` object in my app, I have to take the snapshot of `ExchangePinMutation.Data.ExchangePinForToken.User` and initialise a new `User` object using that: E.g:

```
...
let userSnapshot = data.exchangePinForToken.user?.snapshot
Session.currentUser = User(snapshot: userSnapshot)
...
```

Maybe I'm just creating my fragments and or mutations wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the user property of the `ExchangePinMutation.Data.ExchangePinForToken.User.Fragments` struct should be of the User fragment type, but the type is shadowed by the local ExchangePinMutation.Data.ExchangePinForToken.User type.

I fixed my issue by renaming the `User` fragment to `UserFull` and creating a typealias: `typealias User = UserFull`

Almost no refactoring needed!

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-codegen/issues/394#issuecomment-373323235